# Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm completely new to swift and following a tutorial on creating a to do list app. As soon as i add the question mark in `self.createItem(name: text` i get an error `Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'ViewController'`

```
@objc private func didTapAdd() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Item", message: "Enter new Item", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .cancel, handler: {
            _ in
            guard let field = alert.textFields?.first, let text = field.text, !text.isEmpty else {
                return
            }
            self?.createItem(name: text)
        }))
        present(alert, animated: true)
        
    }
```

Comment: Remove "?" from `self?.createItem(name: text)`. It will look like:  `self.createItem(name: text)`

Comment: Read more about weak self in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not declared self variable as weak to make it optional. Use weak self as below to make the ViewController's self instance as optional. Then you will be able to use question mark.

```
@objc private func didTapAdd() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Item", message: "Enter new Item", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .cancel, handler: { [weak self] (_) in
            guard let field = alert.textFields?.first, let text = field.text, !text.isEmpty else {
                return
            }
            self?.createItem(name: text)
        }))
        present(alert, animated: true)
        
    }
```

Comment: @sokoine please mark the answer accepted as well if it has solved your problem :)